# I can not build with Xcode

Tags: xcode

Trouble
I upgraded `XCODE` from 8 to 9.2,
I got an error message like the one below which made it impossible to build.
I heard that I do not understand the reason.
Can anyone please help me?

Build operation failed without specifying any errors.
Individual build tasks may have failed for unknown reasons.
 I deleted the directories of `Carhage`, `Pods`, `DerivedData`, did Clean Build Folder and rebuilt, but it was useless.

```
environment
XCODE: 9.2
CocoaPods: 1.3.1
Carthage: 0.28.0
```

Comment: can you give more details about error? Post your error as well.

Comment: Make sure you are in .xcworkspace file. Also Xcode 9.3 was just released so you might want to try that.